# Android SettingsActivity popuate ListPreference programatically

Tags: kotlin, android-preferences

How can I populate the items of a `ListPreference` programatically rather than statically from `arrays.xml`?

**SettingsActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

// Do something here to populate the ListPreference bluetoothName...
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
           setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
// ... or here?
// (WTF is a Fragment anyway?)
        }
    }
}
```

**root_preferences.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.preference.ListPreference
        app:dialogTitle="Select bluetooth adapter"
        app:key="bluetoothName"
        app:summary="%s"
        app:title="Bluetooth adapter" />
    <androidx.preference.ListPreference
        app:dialogTitle="Select units"
        app:entries="@array/units_names"
        app:entryValues="@array/units_values"
        app:key="units"
        app:summary="%s"
        app:title="Units"
        />
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for populating the items, but the app crashes when the user selects one

```
    Process: com.rwb.psamfd, PID: 23596
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1
        at androidx.preference.ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onDialogClosed(ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:105)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.onDismiss(PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.java:265)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment$3.onDismiss(DialogFragment.java:120)
        at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1323)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and fuck knows what that means.

You seem to have to give the `ListPreference` an `@array/` otherwise you get `IllegalStateException: ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.`

```
    <androidx.preference.ListPreference
        app:dialogTitle="Select bluetooth adapter"
        app:key="bluetoothName"
        app:entries="@array/empty"
        app:entryValues="@array/empty"
        app:summary="%s"
        app:title="Bluetooth adapter" />
```

```
    <string-array name="empty"></string-array>
```

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // get bluetooth devices
        var cs: Array<CharSequence> = arrayOf("")
        try {
            val bt: BluetoothManager =
                getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager;
            val bta: BluetoothAdapter = bt.adapter;
            val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice> = bta.bondedDevices
            cs = pairedDevices.map { z -> z.name }.toTypedArray()
        }
        catch(e:Exception) {}

        // Start the fragment
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings, SettingsFragment(cs))
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    class SettingsFragment(adapters: Array<CharSequence>) : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        private var adapters: Array<CharSequence> = adapters

        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
           setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)

            val p:ListPreference? = findPreference<ListPreference>("bluetoothName")
            p?.setEntries(adapters)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need

```
            p?.setEntryValues(adapters)
```

as well.